I need help identifying a 3 or 4 in gray pipe in a home built in 1954
During a recent storm water started entering my basement from around where this pipe appears to enter my home.
The home is a one story mid century modern style home on a hill with a basement walkout. I will describe the pipe as entering the home from the front about 5 ft below ground level running inside the home for about 15 ft then turning through a cinderblock wall into a utility room under a screened in porch then turning down into a concrete slab. While the carport looks orginal to the home the brickwork on the back of the home makes me think the screen porch and storage area below might have been added shortly after the home was built or as a design change while building. I plan to address the water issue with a sump pump but I am wondering if removing the pipe and patching the hole will help. The sewerline exits the home about 2 to 3 ft above where the pipe in question enters the home and the gas line enters the home from the opposite corner. 


3 or 4 inch is usually for drain/sewer lines in homes.  Possible the old sewer drain line or a line to drain excess water around the house.
